# How to troubleshoot why telerik radmenu ajax control stops working after form post?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webcenter, plumtree

I have an ASP.NET form with Telerik Ajax RadMenu control hosted in a "portlet" inside a Plumtree portal.  The control works on first load, but then stops after postback occurs.  The postback occurs as a result of submit by another control on the same form.  So this seems Ajax related.  The trouble is the RadMenu stops working.

How to troubleshoot the issue, and learn WHY this is happening?  The second goal being how to resolve, but first things first.

The tools I am familiar with are the IE debugger, and Fiddler 4 (from Telerik).

What tools should I bring into this course?  What links to how-to use these tools?

The environment:

Windows 7 64 with IIS

Oracle WebCenterInteraction ver 10.3.3 (Plumtree)

EDIT:

This ASP.NET form is running fine outside of the portlet.  It is only when I run this inside the portlet do I lose the effect of the radmenu control.

ALSO IMPORTANT TO NOTE:  If I place this form into an iframe and have this served from the portal / portlet, the trouble is resolved.  The problem with this method is that the menus are clipped by the frame.  This form is a "part" in the page.

[Some reading about configuring Portlets](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13174_01/alui/devdoc/docs60/)

UPDATE:

In order to work around this trouble, the farthest I can move forward with the Telerik controls is latest version supporting .NET 2.0.  I suspect the trouble has to do with the Plumtree portal not handling the javascript required in the Ajaxified Telerik controls while producing the inline controls.  Therefore causing the loss of expected control behaviour.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

*Question: What tools should I bring into this course? What links to how-to use these tools?*
*Answer:*
[1.Chrome debugger Tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging)

[2.IE Debugger Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625(v=vs.85).aspx)

I personally found chrome to be my fav one.

***Troubleshooting : *** As source code is not available here, i guess you have used the RadAjaxPanel which leads to update your RadMenu which is not intended in your case. I would suggest you to use RadAjaxManager and to specify the controls you want to update on the button's click.

```
 <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
                <AjaxSettings>
                    <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="UrButtonID">
                        <UpdatedControls>
                            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="ControlIDUWantToUpdate1"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
                            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="ControlIDUWantToUpdate2" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
                            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="ControlIDUWantToUpdate3" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
                        </UpdatedControls>
                    </telerik:AjaxSetting>
                 </AjaxSettings>
            </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

[A Demo with an example is here](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/ajaxmanager/overview/defaultcs.aspx)

Comment: Thanks.  I made an edit to include that the form and controls works outside of the portal / portlet, and not after form submit while running inside the portlet.  It appears to be an issue with how this portal reposts the form contents after submit.  I'm looking for more detail on "how" to use debug tools to see or find the trouble.